# Custom attributes (tags) on SQS Queues

Tags: amazon-sqs

Is it possible to add custom attributes to queues? Preferably via an API but the console if not. I don't mean messages, I mean the actual queue.

Our ops people require this to track usage and do internal billing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to store "custom attributes" about an SQS queue using the SQS API.

However, this type of data could be stored using a DynamoDB table.

As for tracking usage for billing purposes, CloudWatch provides numerous metrics related to each individual queue that you have.

Comment: Thanks !  We will just use a naming convention I think.

Comment: Using a DynamoDB table where your hash key matches the name of the SQS queue seems like it may work for you.